# Perl "do" with a hashed file to convert back to variables - utf8 issue

Tags: perl

I have a function which loads a language file. It uses:

```
my $data = do $file;
```

The file looks like:

```
{
    'lang_About' => 'О нас',
    'lang_About_Italy' => 'О Италии, на русском языке',
    'lang_Account_Information' => 'Информация об учетной записи',
    'lang_Actions_3_dots' => 'Действия ...',
    'lang_Add' => 'добавлять',
    'lang_Add_Link' => 'Добавить ссылку',
    'lang_Add_Review' => 'Добавить отзыв',
    'lang_Add_a_Link' => 'Добавить ссылку'
}
```

This loads it into $data fine- apart from the fact its garbled!

```
'lang_About_Italy' => 'ÃÂž ÃÂ˜Ã‘Â‚ÃÂ°ÃÂ»ÃÂ¸ÃÂ¸, ÃÂ½ÃÂ° Ã‘Â€Ã‘ÂƒÃ‘ÂÃ‘ÂÃÂºÃÂ¾ÃÂ¼ Ã‘ÂÃÂ·Ã‘Â‹ÃÂºÃÂµ',
```

The files are in utf-8 encoding. Am I missing something?

**UPDATE:** doing this seems to work:

```
use open qw(:utf8);
my $language = do $file;
```

How can I tell it to only load that one with "default" utf8? I don't want it to break other read/write's we do

Comment: Try to force use UTF-8 in your sctipt this way: _use utf8; use open qw(:std :utf8);_

Comment: Can you please use `use Encode qw( encode_utf8 );` and in file read operation loop add `$data=encode_utf8($data_line);` for example `my $data_line= "'lang_About_Italy' => 'О Италии, на русском языке'";
my $data = encode_utf8($data_line);` so you will get out in $data as `'lang_About_Italy' => 'О Италии, на русском языке'`

Comment: @Aleksey thanks - I actually came to that solution myself 2 minutes before you posted :) This will affect all other "opens" as well after it, yes?

Comment: @amitbhosale thanks for the reply. Actually, trying to encode the string again just ended up with mod garbled strings (where it was double encoding)

Comment: Use `open my $fh, '<:encoding(utf8)', $filename or die "Couldn't to open $filename"; my $data = do { local $/; <$fh> };`.

Comment: How do you output the data? If you use `Data::Dumper` then it can not print **utf-8** properly in terminal window unless you make some additional configuration for `Data::Dumper`, and your terminal should be configured for **utf-8** codepage (65001). You can verify your code page with following command in windows `chcp`.

Answer (score 3):

There are several things that you should to consider when taking input, and in the previous couple of editions of [Learning Perl](https://www.learning-perl.com) has a Unicode primer appendix.

First, know what encoding your input is. Some program figure this out by forcing everyone to use the same encoding (whatever the developer had, only UTF-8, or whatever). You have to read ("decode") that as the same encoding.

Your Perl program takes its cue from your session settings, but you shouldn't rely on that. Give your amazing program to someone else whose settings might not match yours, and your program isn't so amazing anymore. I recommend always explicitly coding the encodings so you don't rely on local settings:

```
use open qw(:utf8);       # all handles are UTF-8 by default
use open qw(:std :utf8);  # the standard handles are UTF-8
```

This pragma is nice in that it's lexical, so you can apply it to a certain scope without changing the setting for the rest of the program. This is very handy when you have a file that isn't using the default encoding you applied to your program. Here I get to use the other form of `do` that treats a block as a single expression and returns the result:

```
my $data = do {
    use open qw(:encoding(iso-8859-5));
    do $file;
    }
```

Second, if you control the data source, you can decide what the encoding can be. Choose whatever makes sense, document that, and always output things in that format. Many people have settled on UTF-8. Be aware though, that assuming UTF-8 everywhere has the same problem as assuming any other encoding.

Last, if you don't control the data source, you can still easily convert it. I still run into many things that are Latin-1. I find that moving that complexity out of my program into a preprocessing step works well. The [iconv](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/iconv.1.html) program translates between encodings, and now my program can just read UTF-8:

```
$ iconv -f CYRILLIC -t UTF8 some_file
```

Comment: thanks that `do {}` looks interesting. I think thats what I was really looking for :) The inpuit is always going to be utf-8 due to the fact its our own content, and our own website (no one else can re-use the code).

Answer (score 2):

Before your `do` line, put:

```
use open ':encoding(iso-8859-5)';
```

Comment: do you mean *before* not after? I tried it before and it works (but using utf8, as I need to include utf8).

Comment: Why did you change it to "before"? In the question he said the "do" was working in utf8?  His only problem was wanting to restore it back.  That's why mine was "after"... But I think it's better to add a scope around the first "use" to automatically undo it.

Comment: It's not clear in your answer what you meant to do because you didn't explain it. If my edit is wrong and you meant something else, you have to explain it better. In general, a good answer is not only going to show the code, but explain it's motivation and consequences. I don't see anything in the question about restoring anything. Additionally, the person who asked the question says it only works if they put it before the `do` line. These things seem to justify my change.

Answer (score 2):

Please see demonstration code sample bellow.

Note: your terminal should be configured to support `utf8` encoding for output, in windows you can change code page to `65001` with following command `chcp 65001`

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use feature 'say';

use JSON;
use utf8;

use Data::Dumper;

binmode STDOUT, ':utf8';

my $data;
my $fname = shift || die 'Вы не указали имя файла на командной строке';

open my $fh, '<:encoding(utf8)', $fname
    or die "Не удается открыть файл $fname";

$data = do { local $/; <$fh> };

close $fh;

say 'На данный момент мы считали следующую информацию';
say '-' x 35;
say $data;
say '-' x 35;
say 'Теперь доведем её до standard JSON формата';
say '-' x 35;

$data =~ s/'/"/g;
$data =~ s/ =>/:/g;

say $data;
say '-' x 35;
say 'Сделаем конвертацию в perl hash';

my $json = JSON->new();
my $info = $json->decode($data);

say 'Конвертация завершена';

say 'Покажем как все это выглядит через Data::Dumper';
say Dumper($info);

say 'И затем выведем hash как key : value пары';
say '-' x 35;

while(my($k,$v) = each %{$info}) {
    say "$k : $v";
}
```

Output

```
На данный момент мы считали следующую информацию
-----------------------------------
{
    'lang_About' => 'О нас',
    'lang_About_Italy' => 'О Италии, на русском языке',
    'lang_Account_Information' => 'Информация об учетной записи',
    'lang_Actions_3_dots' => 'Действия ...',
    'lang_Add' => 'добавлять',
    'lang_Add_Link' => 'Добавить ссылку',
    'lang_Add_Review' => 'Добавить отзыв',
    'lang_Add_a_Link' => 'Добавить ссылку'
}
-----------------------------------
Теперь доведем её до standard JSON формата
-----------------------------------
{
    "lang_About": "О нас",
    "lang_About_Italy": "О Италии, на русском языке",
    "lang_Account_Information": "Информация об учетной записи",
    "lang_Actions_3_dots": "Действия ...",
    "lang_Add": "добавлять",
    "lang_Add_Link": "Добавить ссылку",
    "lang_Add_Review": "Добавить отзыв",
    "lang_Add_a_Link": "Добавить ссылку"
}
-----------------------------------
Сделаем конвертацию в perl hash
Конвертация завершена
Покажем как все это выглядит через Data::Dumper
$VAR1 = {
          'lang_Add_Review' => "\x{414}\x{43e}\x{431}\x{430}\x{432}\x{438}\x{442}\x{44c} \x{43e}\x{442}\x{437}\x{44b}\x{432}",
          'lang_Actions_3_dots' => "\x{414}\x{435}\x{439}\x{441}\x{442}\x{432}\x{438}\x{44f} ...",
          'lang_About' => "\x{41e} \x{43d}\x{430}\x{441}",
          'lang_Account_Information' => "\x{418}\x{43d}\x{444}\x{43e}\x{440}\x{43c}\x{430}\x{446}\x{438}\x{44f} \x{43e}\x{431} \x{443}\x{447}\x{435}\x{442}\x{43d}\x{43e}\x{439} \x{437}\x{430}\x{43f}\x{438}\x{441}\x{438}",
          'lang_Add_Link' => "\x{414}\x{43e}\x{431}\x{430}\x{432}\x{438}\x{442}\x{44c} \x{441}\x{441}\x{44b}\x{43b}\x{43a}\x{443}",
          'lang_Add' => "\x{434}\x{43e}\x{431}\x{430}\x{432}\x{43b}\x{44f}\x{442}\x{44c}",
          'lang_About_Italy' => "\x{41e} \x{418}\x{442}\x{430}\x{43b}\x{438}\x{438}, \x{43d}\x{430} \x{440}\x{443}\x{441}\x{441}\x{43a}\x{43e}\x{43c} \x{44f}\x{437}\x{44b}\x{43a}\x{435}",
          'lang_Add_a_Link' => "\x{414}\x{43e}\x{431}\x{430}\x{432}\x{438}\x{442}\x{44c} \x{441}\x{441}\x{44b}\x{43b}\x{43a}\x{443}"
        };

И затем выведем hash как key : value пары
-----------------------------------
lang_Add_Review : Добавить отзыв
lang_Actions_3_dots : Действия ...
lang_About : О нас
lang_Account_Information : Информация об учетной записи
lang_Add_Link : Добавить ссылку
lang_Add : добавлять
lang_About_Italy : О Италии, на русском языке
lang_Add_a_Link : Добавить ссылку
```

Comment: Instead of  `binmode STDOUT, ':utf8';`  we can add  `use Encode qw(encode);`  and `$data = do { local $/; encode("UTF-8",<$fh>) };` then just `print $data`.  As per perl monk they gave example `utf8 as an output layer views all output to STDOUT as text strings, converting each codepoint to UTF-8.
But the things you print to STDOUT aren't text strings, they are byte strings. .......` url   https://www.perlmonks.org/?node_id=693402 @polar-bear can you please tell us your view on this?